# Import Dot Net Class

Tags: asp.net

I am completely new to dot net. I have a aspx file that starts out like this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Plural.CoreLib" %>

<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
```

and there is a new object created from a class named Registration:

```
Registration reg = new  Registration();
```

My question is, where is this class coming from? I can't find a folder or anything named Plural.CoreLib (I'm assuming it's coming from there).

Comment: Right click on `Registration` and select `Go to definition`.

Answer (score 0):

`Plural.CoreLib` will be a library that your project references.

If you expand the References on your project then you should see one name Plural.CoreLib. Right clicking on it and selecting properties should tell you where the location of the dll is.

If you install an extension like .NET Reflector then you should be able to right click on `Plural.CoreLib` and select "Go to definition". If that does not work then you can right click on the reference, select Object Browser and then right click on a class you are intrested in and select "Browse Definition"

Comment: I found the dll. Where would the source code be so I can read it (sorry coming from the Python/Linux world and inheriting some old code)? Is there a place in dot net where the source code is compiled? I just want to find out what the piece of code does.

Comment: Edited my answer with a bit more information. There are also other tools that allow you to decompile the entire dll to source code.